# How can I assert a jsForce connection in Node?

Tags: node.js, salesforce

I've got a node app running and almost all routes require access to a live Salesforce connection.

I have exports which login and connect to salesforce like this.

```
# ./modules/sfTools.js
exports.conn = (req, res, next) => {
  conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    loginUrl: process.env.SF_LOGINURL
  })
  next()
}
```

and then the login code is in the same file:

```
exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
  conn.login(process.env.SF_USER, process.env.SF_PASS, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
    if(err) return next(err)
    next()
  })
}
```

In my app.js I require that module and have `app.use(sfTools.conn)` and `app.use(sfTools.login)`.

This is fine, but if I console.log within either function, I see it's calling them both on every page, so it's creating a new connection constantly.

conn.login returns an instanceUrl and accessToken, which the documentation says I can save an use later to establish a connection, but I have no idea how long that accessToken is good for, but it does eventually expire.

How should I set it up to check for a working access token, failing that, login with the username and password, and then repeat the process so I'm not creating a new login every time?